How to update my Change Log script to show how it affected other cells in the spreadsheet
I was able to use the following script to create a change log so I can now see where and when a change occurred across multiple tabs on my spreadsheet:
function onEdit(e) { 
  var sName = e.source.getActiveSheet().getSheetName();  
  if(sName !== "Change log") {
    var value = e.value
    var oldValue = e.oldValue
    var mA1 = e.range.getA1Notation().split(":")[0];
    var time = new Date();    
    if(typeof(e.value) == 'string') {
      var aCell = e.source.getRange(mA1);
      value = aCell.getValue();
      var form = "'" + aCell.getFormula();
    } else {
      value = e.value;      
    }
    var data = [sName, mA1, time, value, oldValue, form];
    e.source.getSheetByName("Change log").appendRow(data);
  }
}

Is there any way that I can see how those changes affected specific cells? For example if the change log documents an update in salaries for February, how did that change affect the fiscal year balance cell (which was updated because of a formula in the cell but wasn't directly changed).

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Please [edit] this question to provide more details.  Include some sample data before and an example of what you'd like to see after.  Show anything you've tried and what worked/didn't work.  As it stands there is no way to understand what you mean .

I am reviewing deleted closed questions.  I was the one who closed this so I'm adding it to the reopen-review queue to allow the community a chance to do its own review to decide if it should remain closed or be reopened.
